SAP: IDoc segments issue with BizTalk middleware since HANA2023 upgrade
Since the upgrade of S/4HANA from version 2020 to 2023, we have been having issues with IDoc segment versions. BizTalk is not accepting our current versions of IDoc segments. I could raise the versions of all the affected versions, but is there an easier way to solve this? See below an example error message found in BizTalk.
I tried sending the IDoc as normal but stumbled upon the issue described below.
Many thanks in advance.
The adapter "WCF-SAP" raised an error message. 
Details "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderGenerationException: 
The segment or group definition E2EDP01008 was not found in the IDoc metadata.
The UniqueId of the IDoc type is:
IDOCTYP/3/ORDERS04/ZORDERS04_027/740.
For Receive operations, the SAP adapter does not support unreleased segments.
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.TypedIdocBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CreateBizTalkMessageStream(Message wcfMessage, IAdapterConfigInboundMessageMarshalling config, TLConfig tlConfig, RLConfig rlConfig)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CreateBizTalkMessage(IBaseMessageFactory messageFactory, IAdapterConfigInboundMessageMarshalling marshallingConfig, Message wcfMessage, TLConfig tlConfig, RLConfig rlConfig)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfMarshaller.CreateBizTalkSubmitMessage(IBaseMessageFactory factory, String inboundTransportLocation, String inboundTransportType, RLConfig config, Message wcfMessage, String ssoToken)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkSubmitBase..ctor(Message message, BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, ControlledTermination control, AsyncCallback realCallback, String ssoToken)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkRequestResponse..ctor(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, String ssoToken, ControlledTermination control)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkOperation.Create(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, String ssoToken, Boolean bizTalkOneWay, BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, ControlledTermination control)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance.BeginOperation(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean bizTalkOneWay)". 


E2EDP01008 is the segment definition of the E1EDP01 segment type. ORDERS04 is the IDoc type, ZORDERS04_027 is the extension, 740 is the release number. Check that these IDoc "objects" exist and are released in the S/4HANA system.
